# Android imei number - how to pick it?

Tags: android, tabs, imei

developed an app using a mobile phone 
used this code to pick imei number

`Utill.class`

```
static TelephonyManager telephonyManager;
public static String getDeviceID(){
telephonyManager=(TelephonyManager) MyApplication.getInstance().getSystemService(MyApplication.getInstance().TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

        return telephonyManager.getDeviceId();

    }

in my job.class

String imeino = Util.getDeviceID();
```

tested with mobile devises and it works properly but when apk installed a tab (in client side )  imei number does not pick and give a null pointer

Note. for tab i have added different layouts and it also works properly in my tab

is this a matter of base url or 
how can i avoid this issue of imei number ?

Comment: for a only wi-fi tablet how can i pick device ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have this common method. Devices without SIM slot will return null IMEI. So pick ANDROID_ID.

```
public String getDeviceID(){ 
    String devcieId;   
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
            devcieId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }else{
             devcieId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
        }
    return devcieId;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

**java Class** and add following code

```
TelephonyManager tel;
TextView imei;                
    tel = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);        
    imei = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
    imei.setText(tel.getDeviceId().toString());
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** and add following code

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer!

Comment: Could you add some details of why this should work? Code-only answers are not very useful and are subject to deletion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code it will return you IMEI number if device GSM based or if not get back the Android ID.

```
String devcieId;   
    TelephonyManager mTelephony = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        if (mTelephony.getDeviceId() != null){
            devcieId = mTelephony.getDeviceId(); 
        }else{
             devcieId = Secure.getString(getApplicationContext().getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID); 
        }
```

Also give the read phone state permission in your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```